# CSS Grab All Class Name Except For Last

Tags: css, sass

I want to grab all the class name ('**my-class**') and change it's color to red **EXCEPT** for the **last one**

Apparently I've been googling and there's no such thing as :last-of-class or whatever. I'm having trouble trying to find a work around **without using JS**.

div1 and div2 are both dynamic! If div2 doesn't exist, then div1 should have the first p element red and the second not.

Please note I left a 'p' tag at the top because I don't want that being part of my selector. I just need the 'my-class' specifically.

or is there a selector I can write to grab all "p"s inside of my-container which include nested P's

```
<p>Some text</p>
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="div1">
    <p class="my-class"></p>
    <p class="my-class"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="my-class"></p>
    <p class="my-class"></p>
    <p class="my-class"></p>
    <p class="my-class"></p>   <!-- This tag should not be red-->
  </div>
</div>
```

I can also use sass so feel free to include that in if need be.

Comment: their parents all have the same class ? ( divs ) ?

Comment: @MihaiT No I need the selector to only be dependent on the class name and not by it's parent's class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the workaround below.

use `div:last-child` . that will select the last `div` in the `container` and if there is only one, it will select it and so...the last `p` from the last `div` will be of other color ( in this example )

```css
.my-container div p.my-class { 
color:red;
}
.my-container div:last-child p.my-class:last-child { 
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="div1">
    <p class="my-class">a</p>
    <p class="my-class">a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="my-class">a</p>
    <p class="my-class">a</p>
    <p class="my-class">a</p>
    <p class="my-class">b</p>   <!-- This tag should not be red-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any SINGLE rule that would do this, but a simple workaround would be to use 2 separate rules in conjunction:

```
.my-class {
  color: red;
}

.div-2 .my-class:last-child {
  color: // whatever you want the default to be
}
```

note that the order is important, setting the last child's color should be done after setting everything first

Comment: I believe this wouldnt make the "LAST" class name to be a custom color. it would make the last "CHILD" of it's parent container become that custom color. Is that correct?

Comment: yeah i think you're right. but if you needed  the last node of a specific parent container to be a custom color, couldn't you do the same thing as above but select/query from within that parent? For example, .div2 .my-class:last-child { color: blue }

Answer (score 1):

This will get the behavior you're looking for without any forced reflow:

```css
.my-class:not(:last-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text</p>
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="div1">
    <p class="my-class">a</p>
    <p class="my-class">b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p class="my-class">c</p>
    <p class="my-class">d</p>
    <p class="my-class">e</p>
    <p class="my-class">f</p>   <!-- This tag should not be red-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, that will color both the last one in "div1" and the last one in "div2" as not red. OP wants only the last one in "div2" to be not red.